# WiFi drops every 10s when downloading a huge file on OS X

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

My WiFi usually works without any problem (Macbook Pro). But sometimes I'll start downloading a huge file (this time a 2Gb file from Google Drive) and the wifi will cut every 10 seconds. It goes like this:

- download starts
- it's downloading quite fast
- after 10-15s the wifi cuts
- wifi is disconnected, download stops
- wifi connects back
- back to step 1

It doesn't happen every time. I've done a WiFi diagnostic but there was nothing particular.

Is that a common problem? Is there something I can do to "debug" that behavior?

I have the exact same problem on another Macbook Pro (both are on latest Yosemite).

Comment: Take your phone (that is connected to your WiFi) and make the same test by downloading the test-file again. If you have a router/wlan combination, you might want to check whether you get the same behavior when you are connected with a network cable. If the problem lies in your WLAN, you can investigate by using the web-interface of your WLAN router. Other than that, it is pretty hard to give any tips.

Comment: 2gB goo drive downloads are a PITA.  Make sure WiFi signal is strong and no interference. wired connection is much safer, more reliable and faster. It could be a dropout from Fading loss or a buffer issue in router from DoS noise.